# Draw a GMSPolyline with a background color

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, mkpolygon

I see that the `GMSPolyline` protocol already defines a `color` property for its stroke color, but is there a way to shade the inside of its polygon (ideally with transparency)? I’m looking for a Google Maps equivalent to `MKPolygon` and friends.

Comment: GMSPolyline is a protocol, not a class!

Comment: not sure if this was different in previous versions of the SDK, but in 1.2 GMSPolyline is clearly a class and no protocol.

Comment: @myell0w They made a bunch of changes recently; this is likely one of them.

Comment: @JeffKelley you're right, they introduced this change with version 1.2: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Answer (score 2):

A Polyline is different to a Polygon's. Polylines' have no concept of a fill color. File a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request) for Polygons to be added to the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, you can get something like this:

[image: Polygons example]

The approach is rather simple:

- Add transparent noninteracting UIView with overriden drawing code and pass it CGPoints for drawing polygons
- Get your `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinates for polygons and convert them to `CGPoints` for drawing
- Update those `CGPoints` every time map moves so you can redraw them in the right position and make that `UIView` redraw itself.

So, what you want to do is add an `UIView` on top of your mapview, which is transparent and non-userinteractive, which has overridden `drawRect` method. It is provided with a double array of CGPoints, like `CGpoint **points,` acccessed with `points[i][j]` where *i* is each of closed polygons and *j* are individual points of each polygon. The class would be, let's call it OverView:

```
#import "OverView.h"

@interface OverView ()
{
    CGPoint **points;
    int *pointsForPolygon;
    int count;
}

@end

@implementation OverView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andNumberOfPoints:(int)numpoints andPoints:(CGPoint **)passedPoints andPointsForPolygon:(int *)passedPointsForPolygon;{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // You want this to be transparent and non-user-interactive

        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        // Passed data

        points = passedPoints; // all CGPoints
        pointsForPolygon = passedPointsForPolygon; // number of cgpoints for each polygon
        count = numpoints; // Number of polygons
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) // For each of polygons, like blue ones in picture above
    {
        if (pointsForPolygon[i] < 2) // Require at least 3 points
            continue;

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

        for(int j = 0; j < pointsForPolygon[i]; j++)
        {
            CGPoint point = points[i][j];

            if(j == 0)
            {
                // Move to the first point
                CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
            }
            else
            {
                // Line to others
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
            }
        }

        CGContextClosePath(context); // And close the path
        CGContextFillPath(context);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}


@end
```

Now, in original `UIViewController` with mapview, you need to have access to all coordinates that make all the polygons (same array as points, but consisting of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, and several others:

```
@interface ViewController () <GMSMapViewDelegate>
{
    CGPoint **points;
    int howmanypoints;
    int *pointsForPolygon;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D **acoordinates;
}
```

`acoordinates` is populated wherever you get your coordinates for polygons, I parse the response string from Fusion Tables, part of my parser method

```
- (void)parseResponse2
{
    NSMutableArray *fullArray = [[self.fusionStringBeaches componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];

    howmanypoints = fullArray.count; // This is number of polygons

    pointsForPolygon = (int *)calloc(howmanypoints, sizeof(int)); // Number of points for each of the polygons
    points = (CGPoint **)calloc(howmanypoints, sizeof(CGPoint *));
    acoordinates = (CLLocationCoordinate2D **)calloc(howmanypoints, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D *));

    for(int i=0; i<fullArray.count; i++)
    {

        // Some parsing skipped here

        points[i] = (CGPoint *)calloc(koji, sizeof(CGPoint));
        acoordinates[i] = (CLLocationCoordinate2D *)calloc(koji, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        pointsForPolygon[i] = koji;

        if (koji > 2)
        {
            // Parsing skipped                
            for (int j=0; j<koji; j++)
            {
                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinates[j].latitude, coordinates[j].longitude);

                // Here, you convert coordinate and add it to points array to be passed to overview
                points[i][j] = [self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:coordinate];
                // and added that coordinate to array for future access
                acoordinates[i][j] = coordinate;
            }
        }
    }

    // Finally, allocate OverView passing points array and polygon and coordinate counts
    self.overView = [[OverView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                                  andNumberOfPoints:howmanypoints
                                          andPoints:points
                                andPointsForPolygon:pointsForPolygon];

     // And add it to view
    [self.view addSubview:self.overView];

}
```

Now, you have Polygons where you want them, but must observe `- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position` delegate method as drawn polygons won't move with map. The trick is that you have your 2D array of coordinates `acoordinates` and you can user helper function `(CGPoint *)[self.mapview.projection pointForCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate]` to recalculate the positions, like:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{    
    if (points != nil)
    {
        // Determine new points to pass
        for (int i=0; i<howmanypoints; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<pointsForPolygon[i]; j++)
            {
                // Call method to determine new CGPoint for each coordinate
                points[i][j] = [self.mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:acoordinates[i][j]];
            }
        }

        // No need to pass points again as they were passed as pointers, just refresh te view    
        [self.overView setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}
```

And that's it. Hope you got the gist of it. Please, comment if I need to clarify something. I can also make a small complete project and upload it to github so you can research it better.